# In webforms, how do I send the current user an email automatically?

Tags: 8, webforms, tokens

I'm trying to send an email to the logged in user who filled out the form without having them enter their email.

The form is made with webforms 8.x-5.x which has a lot of functionality.

I've only tried doing it non-programmatically through the interface by adding an email and using the "custom to email address" where i attempted to use the token: [current-user:mail] which did not work.

I've made a separate email handler for anonymous users, which just uses the email they fill in.

Comment: Have you tried `[webform-authenticated-user:mail]`?

Comment: Suddenly, that works. Could have sworn i tried it in the past without luck. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @huelfe recommended, the token [webform-authenticated-user:mail] actually works for this purpose in the custom to email address.